# Email Experience Manager(EXM) campaign page error

Tags: exm

When I open Exm campaign page it throws error

> "A serious error occurred please contact the administrator"

This error has appeared at the same time on different servers. Sitecore returned  it from "*domain*"*/sitecore/api/ssc/EXM/InitialActiveReviews* request.

Log:

```
5396 09:59:07 ERROR System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'FrameworkDbModel' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at ScCf.Subscription.ServerManager.GetServersByLicenseId(IAppsDataContext ctx, String licenseId) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3937cb50f5c3bdcd\ScCf.Subscription\ServerManager.cs:line 76
   at ScCf.Subscription.ServerManager.GetServer(String licenceId) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3937cb50f5c3bdcd\ScCf.Subscription\ServerManager.cs:line 28
   at Sitecore.Apps.Server.ServerService.GetServer(String licenseId, String password) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3937cb50f5c3bdcd\Sitecore.Apps\Server\ServerService.cs:line 27
   at Sitecore.Apps.Log.Logger.LogWebServiceCall(Credentials credentials) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3937cb50f5c3bdcd\Sitecore.Apps\Log\Logger.cs:line 50
   at Sitecore.Apps.ContextInitializer.Initialize(Credentials credentials, String language) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3937cb50f5c3bdcd\Sitecore.Apps\ContextInitializer.cs:line 31
   at Sitecore.Apps.WebService.WebServiceBase.Execute[T,TResult](Credentials credentials, Func`2 funcToExecute, T t) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3937cb50f5c3bdcd\Sitecore.Apps\WebService\WebServiceBase.cs:line 58
   at Sitecore.Apps.WebService.AppsService.GetServerApplicationsByApplicationId(Credentials credentials, Guid applicationId) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3937cb50f5c3bdcd\Sitecore.Apps\WebService\AppsService\ServerApplications.cs:line 32
```

Thank you.

Comment: While asking such question please be more specific on the Sitecore Version and the tag. For more details on how to ask a question in a better way please follow https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 171121), EXM 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is more related to the on-going update of the Sitecore server-side API performed by our team. It's not expected behavior, so we are working to get it fixed as soon as possible. Please watch the further status here: https://status.cloud.sitecore.net/maintenance/b59d217b-bfed-4066-900c-0e4fba161dac

Comment: Update: should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same problem as of today. I've done some tracing, and EXM appears to be attempting to check its subscription status via this local API call:

https://[CM_SERVER_HOST]/sitecore/api/ssc/EDS/Subscription

That logs the same exception in the EXM logs that you noted: "The model backing the 'FrameworkDbModel' context has changed since the database was created"

By inspecting the outgoing traffic from our CM server, I can see that this is actually coming from an external Sitecore service API call to:

https://apps.sitecore.net/api/Subscriptions(LicenseId='LICENSE_ID_REMOVED')

The response includes the following JSON:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://appcenter.cloud.sitecore.net/api/$metadata#Edm.String","value":"The model backing the 'FrameworkDbModel' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."
}
```

It looks like Sitecore have updated their API, and it's now incompatible with the existing services out in the wild trying to call it. I'll be logging a support request now.

Comment: I can confirm that the fix implemented by Artem's team has resolved my issue.